# How to add hour from another column to date in Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, entity-framework-6

I write that code. I want to use T-SQL DATEADD.

```
var result = dbContext.MyEntity
.Where(DbFunctions.AddHours(g.Date,g.Hour) >= minDate 
&& DbFunctions.AddHours(g.Date,g.Hour) <= maxDate).ToList();
```

When this gets to SQL, I get the error:

> The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data
>   type date

Comment: The error message is trying to tell you the problem. You have a data type of `date` rather than `datetime` and you're using `dateadd(hour)` on that date. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957491/the-datepart-hour-is-not-supported-by-date-function-dateadd-for-data-type-date)

Comment: Ok, I got it. But I could not write new DateTime in here. How could I join that Date and Time, and queriying them. Note: I cannot change db column to Datetime from Date.

Comment: Try following : var result = dbContext.MyEntity
.Where(g => g.Date.AddHours(g.Hour) >= minDate 
&& g.Date.AddHours(g.Hour) <= maxDate).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng .AddHours not using directly when querying database.

Comment: The SQL server uses three parameters for AddHours and you have only two : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @jdweng but I use entity framework linq to access SQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution, may be help someone else;

```
var result = dbContext.MyEntity
.Where(DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(g.Date.Year,g.Date.Month,g.Date.Day,g.Hour,0,0) >= minDate 
&& DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(g.Date.Year,g.Date.Month,g.Date.Day,g.Hour,0,0) <= maxDate).ToList();
```